# focus not getting set on td

Tags: javascript

I am coding for a html wysiwyg editor. I am trying to modify a table already present in the editor. I have a menu from which i can modify rows/columns to the table.

After I insert a new row/column I need to set the focus to the new row/column. This works fine.

But when i delete a row/column, I am not able to set focus to the nearby row/column.

I am setting tabIndex property to td to focus it.

```
tbody.removeChild(tr); //tr is the row to be deleted 
pre_tr.childNodes[td.cellIndex].tabIndex = 1; //pre_tr has the previous tr to be focused
pre_tr.childNodes[td.cellIndex].focus();
```

Any help in this regard is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not all elements could be focused in every browser. Also, it's better to use `pre_tr.cells[td.cellIndex]`, since childNodes may include empty text nodes.

Comment: What is the `td` variable? (Does it reference a cell in the row that was just removed?)

Comment: Likely removing the row changes the cellIndex number. This kind of issue seems common in loops where an [i] is used to go through something unstable like a nodeList, rather than a stable array. One trick around this is to go through the list backwards, but I don't know if you're doing all this within a loop.

Comment: @kirilloid:But I am able to set focus to td when I am adding a new row/column.

Comment: @stommepoes: I am not doing this within a loop. I get the tr which needs to be removed and just remove it. Even if I use a fixed number like 1 the td is not getting focused.

Comment: In chrome, the td is getting highlighted. But no cursor inside the td

Comment: @GauthamRenganathan then the problem may be in that td is deleted as nnnnnn said

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height:900px; background-color:gray;"> DIV A  </div>
<br  />
<div style="height:300px; background-color:#ECECEC;"> DIV B  <input style="border:0px;   background-color:#ECECEC;" readonly="true" type="text" id="b"/> </div>

<script>
document.getElementById('b').focus();
</script>
```

Hopes it will works...
I don't know it was the proper way.

> Something is good for nothing....

Comment: You are able to focus on the input, but Gautham is focusing on things normally not focusable (table data cells) and he's able to do this because he's setting a tabIndex on the element first.

Comment: yes, but we set the bg color of the input field as same as the bg of div and set boder=0 the input field will disappear.

Comment: Just copy and past the code in a html file and run in browsers, you can understand...